# Intellisense working for one project but not for another on same machine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a Unity project on my laptop where intellisense and autocompletion works just fine with visual studio code (mac os system).

Now, i created a brand new project (same Unity version as the old one) and for that project intellisense is not working :O Same machine, same editor, everything else is the same.

Any suggestions on what could fix that since the required dependencies are already installed (the visual studio code output is not giving me any logs or other messages by the way) ?

Comment: Did you ever set `omnisharp.useModernNet = false` in your folder/workspace level settings?

Comment: don't think so, i will try it

Comment: checked the settings in VSCode. Use modern net is checked.

Comment: I mean the settings in your old project, because a folder/workspace level settings won't be brought to your new project. Use modern net should be unchecked for unity to work.

Comment: I actually saw an error which i havent seen before and i updated .NET. Now I am getting this message: "Error: This project targets .NET version that requires reference assemblies that are not installed (e.g. .NET Framework). The most common solution is to make sure Mono is fully updated on your machine (https://mono-project.com/download/) and that you are running the .NET Framework build of OmniSharp (e.g. 'omnisharp.useModernNet': false in C# Extension for VS Code). Downloaded Mono too and unchecked the option, still getting the same issue, but at least i know the issue now.

Comment: Alright, it worked after a while, guess it was loading stuff. Thanks a lot ! The option was the important part. Feel free to make this an answer and will select it, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From omnisharp's [announcements](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode#the-c-extension-no-longer-ships-with-an-included-mono--msbuild-tools)

> If you still need Unity or .NET Framework support, you can set omnisharp.useModernNet to false in your VS Code settings and restart OmniSharp. Please see the Requirements section above to ensure necessary tooling is installed.

So we just need to uncheck **Omnisharp: Use Modern Net** in vscode settings, and beware of the settings precedence.