# OmniSharp requires a complete install of Mono (including MSBuild)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, mono

**OS**: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
**OS Type**: 64-bit
**GNOME Version**: 42.4
**Unity Editor Version**: 2021.3.13f1

---

**Error**:

> OmniSharp requires a complete install of Mono (including MSBuild) to
> provide languages services when `omnisharp.useModernNet` is disabled
> in Settings. Please install the latest Mono and restart.

I am using the Unity Engine on Ubuntu and installed VS Code to develop my games.
Every time I try to open my project on VS Code, this message pops up:

[image]

Everything was fine and running correctly until I installed and ran LXDE for a better performance.
I switched back to GNOME and removed LXDE completely, still didn't work.

My currently installed tools & extensions are:

- C# extension
- dotnet https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/sdk-for-vs-code
- mono https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/
- msbuild [https://launchpad.net/~eofla/+archive/ubuntu/msbuild](https://launchpad.net/%7Eeofla/+archive/ubuntu/msbuild)

```bash
salah@salah-ub:~$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.182 (tarball Tue Jun 14 22:35:00 UTC 2022)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    Interpreter:   yes
    LLVM:          yes(610)
    Suspend:       hybrid
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
salah@salah-ub:~$ msbuild --version
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0 for Mono
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

17.0.0.25701
salah@salah-ub:~$ dotnet --version
6.0.110
```

And my settings:

```json
"omnisharp.path": "latest",
"omnisharp.useModernNet": false,
"omnisharp.monoPath": "/usr/bin/mono"
```

Comment: If you wait a moment, does the message go away? Check the last 2 commits in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74232777/intellisense-working-for-one-project-but-not-for-another-on-same-machine).

Comment: @shingo no it doesn't, and the output is `OmniSharp failed to start because of missing requirements.` when I cancel it.

Comment: Try `"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always"`, there is a [known issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.23.11).

Comment: Microsoft no longer plans to support that Mono mode, https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/2339 So you should stop using your current settings.

Comment: option doesn't exists in v1.25.1

Comment: Solved using C# extension `v1.23.11` and setting `"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always"`, Thanks @shingo and @lex-li

Comment: Downgrading the C# extension to `v1.25.0` should fix it. Source: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5445#issuecomment-1309257414

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved using C# extension `v1.23.11` and setting `"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always"`

Answer (score -1):

Оn OSX Catalina in C# extension v1.25.4

setting
Omnisharp: Mono Path  to "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current" solves it